# Escaping less than sign in paste/system command in R

Tags: regex, r, escaping

I would like to run `head <(cat file.txt)` using system within R, but escaping `<` is a problem.

```
system(paste("head <(cat file.txt)"))
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `head <(cat file.txt)'

I've tried escaping it, but its not working

system(paste("head /<(cat file.txt)"))
head: cannot open `/<(cat file.txt)' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Can someone suggest an alternative.

Cheers

Comment: For this kind of question, it is important to provide what system you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not with escaping `<`. By default, `system` runs the command with `/bin/sh`, and your command is incorrect with this shell :

```
$ sh -c "head <(cat foo.txt)"
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

But it works with bash.

Under R, you can try something like :

```
system("bash -c 'head <(cat file.txt)'")
```